# Positional index in Ember.js collections iteration

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a way to get positional index during iteration in ember.js?

```
{{#each itemsArray}}
     {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm looking for a way to have something like:

```
{{#each itemsArray}}
    {{name}} - {{index}}th place.
{{/each}}
```

**Update:**

As per the comment by @ebryn the below code works without using a nested view for each item:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">    
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.peopleController"}}
        Index {{contentIndex}}: {{content.name}} <br />
    {{/collection}}
</script>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WSwna/14/

Although to have something like adjustedIndex, a nested view would be required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Index in #each in emberjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795562/accessing-index-in-each-in-emberjs)

Comment: Ember 1.11 made this trivial. See my answer below if you're on Ember 1.11+.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's old question but still gets a lot of hits. In the current version of Ember.JS one can use `_view.contentIndex` to display current index inside the loop.

```
{{#each}}
    Index: {{_view.contentIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

If you need an adjusted index (for instance starting from 1) then there is a possibility of creating reusable helper `increment`

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('increment', function(integer) {
    return integer + 1;
});
```

then you would use it in the following way

```
{{#each}}
    Index: {{increment _view.contentIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

**Update**

Starting with ember 1.11 you can do as well

```
{{#each people as |person index|}}
   Index: {{increment index}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually yes you can get the position of the current index using the {{each}} helper. You have to create a view for every item in a list and then use `{{_parentView.contentIndex}}`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#each App.peopleController}}
  {{#view App.PersonView contentBinding="this"}}
    Index {{_parentView.contentIndex}}: {{content.name}} {{adjustedIndex}} <br />
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [ { name: 'Roy' }, { name: 'Mike' }, { name: 'Lucy' } ]
});

App.PersonView = Ember.View.extend(Ember.Metamorph, {
  content: null,
  // Just to show you can get the current index here too...
  adjustedIndex: function() {
    return this.getPath('_parentView.contentIndex') + 1;
  }.property()
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/WSwna/) for a working example.

Comment: Could you please let me know why you need to pass in the Ember.Metamorph behaviour when extending the view?

Comment: You don't "need" to, but adding the `Ember.Metamorph` mixin makes the entire setup perform more like a normal `each` helper (talking speed and memory resources here) than the bloated `collection` helper. If you take a look at the source for the two and compare you'll see what I mean. For large amounts of data it makes a difference.

Comment: it appears that your code does not work with 0.9.8.1 with VIEW_PRESERVES_CONTEXT set to true

Comment: This code and fiddle are for Ember v0.9.3 as it was made 4 months ago. If you need some help with something currently, just ask. :)

Comment: If you were looking for 9.8 or pre-1.0 I put an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870785/positional-index-in-ember-js-collections-iteration/12487312#12487312) at the bottom.  But it really is only to be used if you REALLY need it until `@index` is available.

Comment: I get: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Undefined]

Comment: Methods prefixed with underscores are private and should be avoided.

Comment: Would be excellent/really helpful of you could update this answer, should people stumble on it trying to find a working answer! :)

Comment: If you or anyone edits it I'll be more than happy to accept it. I just don't have time right now to edit answers over 2 years old!

Answer (score 9):

In RC6 `CollectionView` provides `contentIndex` propery for each rendered view of collection. `Each` helper uses `CollectionView` in its implementation so uou can access index in this way:

```
{{#each itemsArray}}
    {{_view.contentIndex}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: WHen i use this in each controller i get weird numbers

Comment: this works for me - i have an array in my controller and i just do something like this: 
                                                        {{#each prospects}}
                                                  
        Index {{_view.contentIndex}}: {{name}} <br />
   
                                                        {{/each}}

Comment: Without specifying the itemViewClass, we can use _view.contentIndex. But that does not work inside a #if helper within the #each. To do that we need to use: {{#each model itemViewClass="Ember.View"}}
    {{#if someCondition}} {{view.contentIndex}} {{/if}}
{{/each}} "Specify an itemViewClass"

Answer (score 6):

As of Ember 9.8 and pre-1.0 you can wrap the "contentIndex" with a view in order to get at the virtual parent (the {{#each}}).  If you don't add the view, your context ends up being either the main template, an item in your list or whatever you manually set with your `{{#with}}`.  It is not impossible to get at the `{{#each}}` from the JS side but it is a lot more of a pain flipping through those child views.

```
{{#each App.peopleController}}
    {{#view}}
        Index {{view._parentView.contentIndex}}: {{name}} <br />
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}

...OR...

{{#each people in App.peopleController}}
    {{#view}}
        Index {{view._parentView.contentIndex}}: {{people.name}} <br />
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

Just in-case you would like a fiddler.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/g36as/1/)

Note: You can create a view and do a `this.get("_parentView.contentIndex")` to get at the index if you want to modify the number at all.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't currently a feature of Handlebars or `Ember.Handlebars`. We have `contentIndex` available inside `#collection`/`Ember.CollectionView`. I think it's useful to support in `#each` too. Please file an issue at the GitHub repository: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues

Comment: Update to this: Handelbars has gained [support for `@index`](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/commit/5e8be14d78f87e73878e4d29013482f7daff9d8a). It's not usable in Ember.Handlebars yet, but I imagine it will be sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

As of Ember 1.11.0, `index` is an optional parameter in `each` blocks:

```
{{#each items as |item index|}}
  {{item.name}} is at index {{index}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the help steve!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified a bit ud3323 solution using collection.
Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/johngouf/WSwna/13/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">    
{{#collection contentBinding="App.peopleController"}}
  {{#view App.PersonView contentBinding="this"}}
    Index {{_parentView.contentIndex}}: {{content.name}} {{adjustedIndex}} <br />
  {{/view}}
{{/collection}}
</script>

App = Ember.Application.create();
App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
 content: [ { name: 'Roy' }, { name: 'Mike' }, { name: 'Lucy' } ]
});

App.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
 content: null,
 // Just to show you can get the current index here too...
 adjustedIndex: function() {
    return this.getPath('_parentView.contentIndex') + 1;
 }.property()
});
```

​​

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably do something like this too

```
//add index property to all each queries
Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(context, block) {
    var ret = "";
    for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
        context[i].index = i;
        ret = ret + block(context[i]);
    }
    return ret;
});
```

Comment: I had done that, but didn't feel right to override behavior of inbuilt iterator.