# How to pass parameters with the action Helper of Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a list of items:

```
  <ul>
    {{#each applications}}
      <li>
        <a {{bindAttr href="url"}} 
        {{action "appClicked" on="click"}}>                
           {{name}}
        </a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

On click it calls the method `appClicked` of the view, that this template belongs to. I want to pass some information (for example, the name of the application) to the method `appClicked`. Something like, `{{action "appClicked(name)" on="click"}}`.

Is it possible, and how?

Comment: There isn't currently a way to do what you want and I'd think that doing so doesn't quite sound right. I know this is just a small snippet of whatever you're trying to do but you shouldn't need to pass the `name` property (or any for that matter) to your action. The target should be the current view in the list. 

Could you provide a jsFiddle and maybe explain a bit more what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is possible to do the answer here from the API http://stackoverflow.com/a/18473842/551811

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was thinking something more along the lines of this since you'll have access to a bunch more through an actual view. But Zack, if you could explain a bit more what exactly you're trying to do if this isn't what you're looking for?

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [ { name: 'Roy', url: '#' },
               { name: 'Mike', url: '#' }, 
               { name: 'Lucy', url: '#' } ]
});

App.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    content: null,
    linkClicked: function() {
        console.log(this.getPath('content.name'));
    }
});
```

```html
<ul>
{{#each App.peopleController}}
    {{#view App.PersonView contentBinding="this"}}
        <a {{bindAttr href="content.url"}} {{action "linkClicked" on="click"}}>
            {{content.name}}
        </a>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I saw that solution, somewhere on SO (answered by Katz). As I understand, you have to create a separate View for *every* element that you want track events from (click, focus, etc.). Am I correct? I also found this pull https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/451 , not sure if this what I'm looking for.

Comment: I explained it in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870785/positional-index-in-ember-js-collections-iteration/) too and yes you are correct. There are some performance concerns with rendering very large lists using regular views (one of the reasons the #collection helper is being depreciated I believe). However, if you look at my solution I change the child view to a Metamorph view which just about eliminates the performance difference between #collection and #each helpers. Anyway, this is the way you probably should do this. I wouldn't be too concerned w/ that pull req.

Comment: I've created a version of the jsfiddle in this answer that is compatible and idiomatic for Ember 1.0. Feel free to update your answer with this link, Roy: http://jsfiddle.net/tL4Xt/

Answer (score 19):

Apparently, Ember has evolved now and there is an ability to pass a parameter to an action:

```
{{action "functionName" parameter}}
```

In your case, that would be:

```
<a {{bindAttr href="url"}} 
   {{action "appClicked" name on='click'}}>                
       {{name}}
   </a>
```

However, you could pass any attribute from the model (like the id) instead of the name.

See http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/ for more information.

Answer (score 19):

[The API says](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action) you can pass in multiple parameters.

html and handlebars:

```
{{officename}} 
<button {{action "actionTest" "hello" "goodbye" officename}}>See parameters through action in the console</button>
```

controller:

```
actionTest: function(a, b, c){
   console.log(a);
   console.log(b);
   console.log(c);
},
```

[See it in action in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/426/edit)

Comment: As of the Ember 1.0 release, this JSBin no longer runs. You may want to update it @HaoQu Li

Answer (score 1):

From subviews, you can attach data-attributes and access them in your controller.

For example, in your view, if you have:

```
{{#view Ember.Button target="App.controller" action="publish" data-publish=false}}Unpublish{{/view}}
```

Then in your controller,

```
App.controller = Ember.Object.extend({
  publish: function(v){
    var status = v['data-publish'];//your additional information is appended to the view.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to Veeb's answer, remember you have the jQuery event so you can do:

```
// template
<ul>
  {{#each applications}}
    <li>
      <a {{bindAttr href="url"}} param="abc" {{action "appClicked" on="click"}}>
         {{name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

// In your js code
appClicked: function (event) {
    var param = $(event.target).attr('param');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to make the parameter an attribute of the <li> or <a> tag and then use jQuery to access it.

Maybe something like

```
// template
<ul>
  {{#each applications}}
    <li>
      <a {{bindAttr href="url"} param="abc"} 
      {{action "appClicked" on="click"}}>                
         {{name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

// In your js code
appClicked: function (event) {
    // You may have to play around and check which DOM element
    // has the the param attribute. From memory it is the parent.
    var param = this.$().parent().attr('param');
    ...
}
```