# ember.js contentIndex for each helper

Tags: ember.js

I have the following handlebars template:

```
   {{#each Lead.leads_controller}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>{{???}}</strong>
      </td>
      <td class="plus expander">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>{{company}}</td>
      <td>{{web}}/</td>
      <td>{{phone_1}}</td>
      <td>{{phone_2}}</td>
      <td>{{fax}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

I want to show a 1 based index for each row in a table.  I know previously the collectionView had contentIndex exposed but this does not appear to be the case for the each helper.

I found [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/523) that seems to suggest that this is not available for the each helper.  Is there any way of making this possible for the each helper?

Comment: Yes you can. I actually answered this about [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870785/positional-index-in-ember-js-collections-iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870785/positional-index-in-ember-js-collections-iteration). Please close as this is a repeat question.

Comment: It does not work with the each helper.  I could be wrong but I don't think you have access to _parentView with each.  I believe #collection is going to be deprecated at some point soon.

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you run the jsFiddle?

Comment: it does not work with #each.  That is the point.  Can you read the comment I wrote above.

Comment: So [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/rTMEg/) isn't what you're looking for? That does not solve your issue? You get access to contentIndex within the each helper. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that is it.  Thanks a lot.  I could not work out how to get _parentView from each.

Comment: How can we change the index to start count form 1 (like non-developers do)?

Comment: Related question with answer for most recent Ember: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788658/1877270