# Ember: concat attributeBinding, how to?

Tags: ember.js, concatenation, handlebars.js

I need to concat several variables to create one attribute, for an example I have a set of [RadioButtons](http://thoughts.z-dev.org/2013/07/04/radio-buttons-in-ember-js/) which may appear several times on the page - dynamically, first the view can be displayed severl time, other thing is that they are placed in `each` loop so they can appear several times per view.

So I can't use static `name` attribute, but I should concat if with several parts, for an exampe result should look like:

```
<input name="view1_row0" value="0"> No
<input name="view1_row0" value="1"> Yes

<!-- next row in view1 -->
<input name="view1_row1" value="0"> No
<input name="view1_row1" value="1"> Yes

<!-- next row in view2 -->
<input name="view2_row0" value="0"> No
<input name="view2_row0" value="1"> Yes
```

etc... I can easily get the parent's view's ID and/or index of the loop with [`view._parentView.contentIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927759/1066240) but I have no idea how to concat them in one binding, the pseudo code would look like this:

```
{{view Ember.RadioButton nameBinding=view.parentView.elementId + "_row" + view._parentView.contentIndex selectionBinding="someVal" value="0"}}
```

But it of course throws the error at `+` sign. Is there any way to resolve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass them in as separate bindings and the concatenate them in a custom implementation of `Ember.RadioButton`?

```
{{view App.MyRadioButton elementIdBinding="view.parentView.elementId" contentIndexBinding="view._parentView.contentIndex" selectionBinding="someVal" value="0"}}
```

and then in `App.MyRadioButton` (which extends `Ember.RadioButton`)

```
name: function() {
   return this.get('elementId') + '_row' + this.get('contentIndex');
}.property('elementId', 'contentIndex')
```

Alternatively you might also be able to do that in your controller.

Comment: Hehe, I just finished something similar with `init` function of the view + separate bindings, anyway your solution is cleaner, thx, works like a charm!