# In Ember 1.13 and later what key should I use with each when iterating over an array of strings?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember 1.13 the following code generates a warning:

```
{{#each widgetNames as |widgetName|}}
  {{component widgetName removeWidget="removeWidget"}}
{{/each}}
```

Where widgetNames is an array of strings  in a parent controller.

```
widgetNames: []
```

In Ember 1.13 I now get this warning:

> WARNING: Using `{{each}}` without specifying a key can lead to unusual
>   behavior.  Please specify a `key` that identifies a unique value on
>   each item being iterated. E.g. `{{each model key="@guid" as |item|}}`.

This would be easy enough to fix in you typical model scenario, but how do I specify a key for an array of strings?

**Edit**: This question handles a warning you now get in Ember 1.13 when iterating over an array of strings. If you hit this warning you are not explicitly looking to find the @index parameter like [Accessing Index in #each in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795562/accessing-index-in-each-in-emberjs). Infact, Artych's answer shows two other possible keys to use that would not be relevant or present in an answer to [Accessing Index in #each in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795562/accessing-index-in-each-in-emberjs) as this is specific to the @index parameter itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Index in #each in emberjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795562/accessing-index-in-each-in-emberjs)

Comment: This has changed quite a lot since that original questions @Kitler

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE (Jun,18)**
In Ember 1.13.2 default `key="@identity"` is used, to prevent users from having to specify a `key=` to each `{{each}}` invocation.

`@guid` and `@item` are deprecated in favor of the new default.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v1.13.2
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11461

================= Answer for Ember 1.13, 1.13.1 =========

You could use `key="@index"` or `key="@item"`.

There are a few special values for `key` [( docs )](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_specifying-keys):

- `@index` - The index of the item in the array.
- `@item` - The item in the array itself.  This can only be used for arrays of strings
    or numbers.
- `@guid` - Generate a unique identifier for each object (uses `Ember.guidFor`).

  ```
  {{#each widgetNames key="@index" as |widgetName|}}
     {{component widgetName removeWidget="removeWidget"}}
  {{/each}}
  ```