# Ember 1.13 each loop in each loop

Tags: ember.js

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30845290/2049986), Ember 1.13 needs a key for the `{{each}}` helper. Since Ember 1.13.2 the default key is `@identity`.

Now I am trying to fix my code, I have an each loop nested inside another (piece of code that shows an calendar). I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Duplicate key found ('(null)') for '{{each}}' helper, please use a unique key or switch to '{{#each model key="@index"}}{{/each}}'.
```

But even if I add a `@guid` as key, the error is still shown. Code:

```
{{#each weeks key="@guid" as |week|}}
    <tr>
        {{#each week key="@guid" as |day|}}
            <td class="day"></td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I don't understand that. As `@guid` should create an unique identifier for each object, why do I still get this `duplicate key found` error?

---

**EDIT**:
My assumption that `Duplicate key found` had anything to do with nested each loops was plainly wrong. After trying to build a fiddle as Kitler proposed, I did understand my problem (see the answer).

Comment: That question you have linked to states **@guid and @item are deprecated in favor of the new default.**

Comment: That's just my question, the `new default` does not work if you have a loop wrapped inside a loop. If you got a 'normal' loop, the default makes it easier (because you don't have to do anything).

Comment: You don't need a key if you aren't using it...

Comment: @Kitler: I got an error if i don't provide keys....

Comment: Can you setup your example in a [bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/)?

Comment: I'm getting the same error `Error: Duplicate key found ('ember850') for '{{each}}' helper, please use a unique key or switch to '{{#each model key="@index"}}{{/each}}'` when upgrading from 1.12.1 to 1.13.5

Comment: @pixelhandler: I think you provided an object twice (or more) in your list, so Ember will generate the same key for the same object. See my answer below, actually the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression in v1.13.x and expected to be resolved in a patch, perhaps v1.13.6

This is the closed issue : https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11549

And the merged pull request: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11861

Comment: Confirmation: Ember 1.13.6 does indeed fix this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v1.13.6 -> #11861 [BUGFIX] Update HTMLBars to allow duplicate {{each}} keys.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error, I did understand what was causing the error.

**Cause**
Some items in my loop where `null`. Ember 1.13.x and up tries to add an id for every item. As `null` means nothing, the first `null-item` get key `null`, as Ember provides a *nothing-key* to nothing. The following `null-items` also get a *nothing-key* as Ember does that for every `null-item`.

**Error**
Because the helper requires a unique id for every item, Ember throws an `Duplicate key found ('(null)')` error; telling the programmer some items has the same id.

**Solution**
Fixing this is quite easy, just provide an empty object (`{}`) instead of `null`. As one empty object is not the same as another empty object, Ember will create an unique id for every empty object!

---

Code example: [Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yejazuxota/edit?html,css,js,output).